# find all common divisible numbers given set of divisibles

Tags: javascript, primes, algebra, prime-factoring, khan-academy

Find other common divisible numbers given set of numbers

I am essentially trying to solve what's in the video using javascript. I can get all prime factors. but I am not sure how to produce combined array of prime factors. Then find all permuatations of that.

https://youtu.be/zWcfVC-oCNw?t=4m32s

e.g. `X` is a number is divisible by 9 and 24. Therefore `X` is also divisible by....?

```
function primeFactors(num) {
    let n = num
    let divisor = 2;
    let primes = [];
    while (divisor <= num) {
        if (num % divisor === 0) {
            primes.push(divisor);
            num /= divisor;
        } else {       
            divisor++;
        }

    }

    return primes;
}

console.log(primeFactors(9)) // [3, 3]
console.log(primeFactors(24)) //[2, 2, 2, 3]

// All combinations of [2, 2, 2, 3, 3] are valid answers
```

Comment: [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)(a, b) = a * b / [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)(a, b)

Comment: @Phylogenesis hmmm I am not trying to find common multiples? for e.g. 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 is valid answer. I am saying if X can be divided by 9 and 24 it also can be divided by 8? but at the beginning I don't know if 8 is a valid answer?

Comment: It complicated to state, but basically factor all the divisors you have into prime-power form, e.g. 9 = 3^2, 24 = 2^3 * 3^1.  Now take the max over all the exponents of the primes, so for 2 the max exponent is 3, for 3 the max exponent is 2, for 5 the max exponent is 0, etc. Now iterate over every possible value of the exponent from 0 to max for each prime. Every such choice yields a distinct divisor of X. The all-zeroes exponent gives you the divisor 1, which you may want to suppress depending on how you're counting.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Java.

```
/*
* Example solution to finding all possible numbers divisible by two different numbers.
* In response to stack overflow question at the following URL:
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368860/find-all-common-divisible-numbers-given-set-of-divisibles
* Author James Pata
* Date 01/05/18
*/

public class primeFactorization
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //CHOOSE ANY RANGE OF NUMBERS (>= 1 only)
      int testRange = 216;

      //CHOOSE ANY Two Numbers to Compare Divisibility Similarities 
      int number1 = 9;
      int number2 = 24;

      System.out.println("All numbers divisble by either " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " are: \n");      

      /*
      *The for loop will iterate through the testRange of numbers to be analyzed starting at 1.
      *The for loop has two local variables called tempVariabel that holds the remainder.
      *These tempVariables will be used to determine if divisible, and will then print corresponding confirmation
      * The final else statement was excluded intentionally to prevent the index variable, testNumber, from printing
      */
      for(int testNumber = 1; testNumber <= testRange; testNumber++) 
      {

         int tempVariable1 = testNumber%number1;
         int tempVariable2 = testNumber%number2;

         if(isNumberDivisibleBy(number1, testNumber) && isNumberDivisibleBy(number2, testNumber)) {
            System.out.println(testNumber + " is divisible by both " + number1 + " and " + number2);
            } else if(isNumberDivisibleBy(number1, testNumber)) {
                  System.out.println(testNumber + " is divisible by " + number1);
               } else if(isNumberDivisibleBy(number2, testNumber)) {
                  System.out.println(testNumber + " is divisible by " + number2);
                  }
       }

    }//endmain

    /*
     *The isNumberDivisbileBy takes two parameters, and returns true if
     *parameter testNumber is evenly divisible by number of choosing.
     *(testNumber is determined later determined by the for loop in the main method.)
     */   
    public static boolean isNumberDivisibleBy(int number, int testNumber)
    {
      if (testNumber%number == 0) {
         return true;
         } else { return false; }
    }

}//endclass
```

Outcome:

```
All numbers divisble by either 9 andS 24 are: 

9 is divisible by 9
18 is divisible by 9
24 is divisible by 24
27 is divisible by 9
36 is divisible by 9
45 is divisible by 9
48 is divisible by 24
54 is divisible by 9
63 is divisible by 9
72 is divisible by both 9 and 24
81 is divisible by 9
90 is divisible by 9
96 is divisible by 24
99 is divisible by 9
108 is divisible by 9
117 is divisible by 9
120 is divisible by 24
126 is divisible by 9
135 is divisible by 9
144 is divisible by both 9 and 24
153 is divisible by 9
162 is divisible by 9
168 is divisible by 24
171 is divisible by 9
180 is divisible by 9
189 is divisible by 9
192 is divisible by 24
198 is divisible by 9
207 is divisible by 9
216 is divisible by both 9 and 24
```

If you would like to include numbers that fall below the two chosen numbers to compare, It would be easy to expand this code to include that feature. However, mathematically I would argue that any number smaller than the two given numbers,can never be divisible BY 9 or 24. (because the result would always be a non-improper fraction, and thus a decimal less than one)

However, if you rearranged the logic, to state "which numbers divide INTO 9 or 24" than I could agree with that kind of logic. And once again, expanding this would not be difficult. Although, I would be tempted to clean up my functions to do one thing, and one thing only. Which in Java, would most likely include clean coding practices different than javascript.

***If this did not help answer your question, please be more descriptive with what you exactly want done. I can re-write the code, then translate it into javascript*** (I am decent in javascript, but stronger in Java)